# POST data is always NULL, works on dev

Tags: php, apache, post, laravel-4

I'm having an weird issue. A website just suddenly stopped working correctly. Every time I try to post a form all input is NULL. This used to work (on live) and nothing has changed (code-wise). At first I thought I was hacked or something, but I tested on my local machine and all works fine. So it shouldn't be my code

My question is then: what could be causing the problem? I'm using Laravel 4.1 and it's on an Apache server (my local environment is also Apache). My guess is, it's something on the server, since my code works as expected on localhost.

Route:

```
Route::post('user/login', array('as'=>'user.login','uses'=>'UserController@postLogin'));
```

Postlogin:

```
public function postLogin()
{
    var_dump($_POST);
```

View:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://example.com/user/login" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
            <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-item form-item-100 f-left">
            <input 
                type="email" 
                name="email" 
                placeholder="Email" 
                value="" 
            >
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-item form-item-100 f-left">
            <input 
                type="password" 
                name="password" 
                placeholder="Password"  
            >
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-item form-item-40 f-left">
            <button class="btn btn-green form-submit" type="submit">Log in</button>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: how do you post and read post?

Comment: Can you show us the form?

Comment: try http://weblint4u.com/form-validation-post-and-retain-form-data-laravel/

Comment: @RakeshSharma : as I said, code works fine on local environment.

Comment: then may be check to sure case sensitive of controller/ views name

Comment: Views are rendered perfectly and when I use var_dump() in my controller I see the output (so my controller is called). My guess is this isn't the problem either. As I said, it used to work fine for months on end now...

Comment: Might be worth validating the output HTML in case it is malformed in a way that stops it working in some cases. Also, if it recently stopped working, assess what changed on the server.

Comment: @halfer expect for minor warnings, it's W3C validated

Comment: What happens if you take `accept-charset` out of the opening tag?

Comment: @Gregory Most likely a difference in PHP version. Compare your php version on your production and local machine.

Comment: @Mystoryos local: 5.4.10, live: 5.4.31

Comment: @Halfer: same result...

Comment: Try adding a test page on a different vhost without Laravel getting in the way. I wonder if it is clearing the POST superglobal in rare circumstances.

Comment: To be sure it's a server issue, create a form using just html and submit to a standalone php script not using Laravel and see if the POST array is populated.

Comment: Also, disable JavaScript in your browser temporarily, in case it's something your client is doing.

Comment: Load your page then add `var_dump($_POST)` at the top of your index.php then submit form.

Comment: Do you get any POST data dumping Input::all() ?

Comment: @ABoyNamedSu The POST data is when using standalone form, so it has to be something else :s

Comment: Never mind, the laravel form works now to... What the hell is going on here

Comment: Could this in any way be a PHP cache issue? I know Laravel and XCache (or was it APC?) have problems working together

Comment: @ABoyNamedSu bad phrasing: the POST data was set when using a standalone form. So I thought the error came from Laravel, but see comment below, the forms in Laravel started working again too... I'm really curious at wat was going on...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was indeed with the hosting. The exact details of what the problem was are unknown to me...